# What is it called when I instantiate an object in PHP and then declare variables inside that object?

Tags: php, object

I know this is not great practice, but I need a definition in order to get my real question answered.

I have an object like this:

```
class Car
{
   public $wheel;
   public $engine;
   so on..
}
```

I instantiate and edit values like thus:

```
myCar = new Car();
myCar->wheels = 4;
myCar->engine = V8;
```

What is it called when I do this?:

```
myCar->brakes = "disc";
```

It populates the new key and value in the existing object, but I don't know the name for that.

**Update:**  I removed the parentheses.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you are creating and assigning a new instance variable inside of the `myCar` object.

Comment: Perfect thanks. Do you know of a way to lock an object down to avoid inadvertent variable loading?  The class I have built loads up from a mySql select, but on save it simply iterates through the $_POST to update the table.  As I write this, I notice the security issues, but I want a way to lock the object to the existing table fields.  Any pointers?

Comment: You could use the magic `__set` method, and only allow x variables to be set.

Comment: Obviously, this would only work with instance data that is not directly accessible.

Comment: Jacob, I could kiss you.  That was exactly what I needed!  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

isnt that you created a public variable brakes inside myCar instance on the fly??
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

but Class Car doesn't have brakes, so when u new Car again, no brakes.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating ***object properties*** (variables that are part of a class).

Comment: i think you meant 'variables that are part of an object', 'variables that are part of a class' would be `static`.